# azure command line script to run node js command

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have hosted a nodejs app on azure linux. Now, I am trying to run command from my machine to invoke node js cli command. I am looking for an ability to run the script from my local machine on server.

I am trying

```
az vm run-command invoke -g xxx -n yyy --command-id RunShellScript --scripts “NODE_ENV_VAR_LIST node dist/app.js arg1 “
```

Output , it say provisioning is successful but throw error while running

```
"Enable succeeded: \n[stdout]\n\n[stderr]\nmodule.js:549\n    throw err;\n    ^\n\nError: Cannot find module '/var/lib//run-command/download/2/dist/app.js'\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)\n    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)\n    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)\n    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3\n",
```

any help is appreciated?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error gives enough message. Let's analyze it again. The success means the script `NODE_ENV_VAR_LIST node dist/app.js arg1` was executed in the VM, if it does not succeed, then it means VM does not execute the command.

And the error after is about the command, it means there is something wrong with the command itself. And the issue is also clear, you use the relative path and it causes the issue. You need to use the absolute path for the app file in the command.